# How to test sh script return status with jenkins declarative pipeline new syntax

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Using new jenkins declarative pipeline syntax, I'd like to test the return status of a sh script execution. Is it possible without using script step?

Script pipeline (working) :

```
...
stage ('Check url') {
   node {
    timeout(15) {
      waitUntil {
        sleep 20
        def r = sh script: "wget -q ${CHECK_URL} -O /dev/null", returnStatus: true
        return (r == 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Declarative pipeline (try) :

```
...
      stage('Check url'){
        steps {
            timeout(15) {
                waitUntil {
                    sleep 20
                    sh script: "wget -q ${CHECK_URL} -O /dev/null", returnStatus: true == 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

log : java.lang.ClassCastException: body return value null is not boolean

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that without wrapping it in a `script {}` and doing the the comparison like you do in the first example. There is just no way to get the shell to return anything but an integer, and no way to coerce that integer to a Boolean without being in a script.

Comment: I agree. Everything which has a bit more logic needs the `script` block. That's why it exists.

Comment: In general there's no need for a `sleep`, because `waitUntil` sleeps itself.

Answer (score 6):

Since it's not possible without script block, we get something like :

```
...
stage('Check url'){
        steps {
            script {
                timeout(15) {
                    waitUntil {
                        sleep 20
                        def r = sh script: "wget -q ${CHECK_URL} -O /dev/null", returnStatus: true
                        return r == 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```